# Git instalattion, unmet or you have held broken packages

Tags: applications, software-installation, apt, dependencies, release-loki

Loki Beta running smoothly.

Unable to install Git-
Tried with numerous methods no Luck.

I receive 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

have tried the following to no avail.
apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo dpkg -r --force-all git
apt-get install --reinstall git
apt-get install perl
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo dpkg --configure -a
apt-get check
apt-get -f install
apt-get install liberror-perl
apt-get autoremove
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
Guess what solved the solution. I'm a bloody idiot!

I'll leave this here , so If any one else has issues like this, the solution is so simple. So easily to over look.

As Loki is a beta, I did not check to see if ticked, "Software & updates", then "Ubuntu Software" tick box " Community maintained (Universal)" .

Then do the usuall stuff, as above. will fix the problem,
 unmet dependencies.

I hope this helps others !

Answer (score 1):

Guess what solved the solution. I'm a bloody idiot!

I'll leave this here , so If any one else has issues like this, the solution is so simple. So easily to over look.

As Loki is a beta, I did not check to see if ticked, "Software & updates", then "Ubuntu Software" tick box " Community maintained (Universal)" .

Then do the usuall stuff, as above. will fix the problem,
 unmet dependencies.

I hope this helps others !